# Jumps of càdlàg martingale at predictable time

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-processes, martingales

I'm kind of struggling with jumping behavior of some basic processes coming from the Doob-Meyer decomposition. Unfortunately I couldn't find a book that elaborates enough on this, but if anybody knows one, this would be tremendously helpful!

Let $M$ be a càdlàg $\mathcal{F}_t$-martingale and $\tau$ be a predictable stopping time. Is it always true, that 
$$
E[\Delta M(\tau)]=E[E[\Delta M(\tau)|\mathcal{F}(\tau-)]]=0?
$$
Why does it hold true and where can I find more on this topic?

Also:
If $A$ is the predictable compensator coming from the Doob-Meyer decomposition of a càdlàg submartignale and $\tau^{A}$ is it's first jump, is $\tau^{A}$ predictable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first equality comes from the law of total expectations.

Comment: Yeah or simply from the tower property, but why is it always (allegedly) zero? I have only found this for bounded martingales in Kallenberg?

Comment: Take a look at Lemma 2 [here](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/compensators/)